# unable to view list item onhover in IE, works with Mozilla/chrome

Tags: php, html

i am not understanding how to make it work in IE,this code is working for mozzila and chrome,when i hover on register i am not able to see A register and B Register list items,any help will be appreciated.This is php code

```
<?php
$list.="<li ><a href=\"\">Register</a>
                <ul><li><a href=\"a.php\">A Register</a></li>
                <li><a href=\"b.php\">B Register</a></li></ul>
                </li>";
                ?>
```

and this is css

```
 /* Lists */
    ul, ol {
        margin: 10px 20px;
        padding: 0 20px;
    }
    ul { list-style: disc; }
    ol { list-style: decimal; }
    /* Header */
    #header {
        position: relative;
        margin: 0 auto;
        height: 245px;      
    }
    /*  navigation  */
    #header #nav {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0px;  bottom: 20px;       
        margin: 0; padding: 0 0 0 20px;     
        width: 900px;       
        border-bottom: 1px solid #F2F2F2;   
        /* z-index: 99999; */
    }
    #header #nav ul {
        float: left;    
        list-style: none;   
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;                 
    }
    #header #nav ul li {

        float: left;
        margin: 0; padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
        position: relative;
        display: inline;
    }
    #header #nav ul li a:link,
    #header #nav ul li a:visited {
        float: left;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 5px 15px 10px 15px;
        color: #666666;
        font: bold 14px 'Trebuchet MS', Arial, Sans-Serif;
        text-transform: uppercase;      
        border-right: 1px solid #EEE;   
    }
#header #nav ul li a:hover{background-color: #D14836;
color: #FFFFFF; 
} 
#header #nav ul li a:active {
    diasplay:block;
    border: none;
    color: #000;    
    border-right: 1px solid #EEE;
}
#header #nav ul li#current a {  
    background: transparent url(../images/current.gif) repeat-x left bottom;    
    color: #222;    
}

#header #nav ul li.first a:link, 
#header #nav ul li.first a:visited {
    border-left: 1px solid #F1F1F1; 
}
```

Comment: not really clear what is not working for you, there must be other code dependencies you didnt show, http://jsfiddle.net/7Ve2P/

Comment: when i hover on register,i am not able to see its list items in IE ,with same code which i am able to see in chrome and Mozilla

Comment: It'd be great to see a jsfiddle with the rendered HTML, and CSS that you're using. I can see things in your CSS ('.first', and 'diasplay') typos that may or may not be causing your problem. For example, if you're trying to use `.first` in place of `:first-child`, IE will laugh at you.

Answer (score 0):

It could have to do with the fact that you're using a really old browser (IE6) which doesn't recognize the :hover pseudo selector in your css, in IE6 it wil only recognize :hover on anchor tags.

If for whatever reason you really need to support IE6 have a look at the following solution:

[Hover whatever](http://peterned.home.xs4all.nl/csshover.html)

Comment: He's only using `hover` in one place. And it's on an `a` element.